# Relative Layout Change Background color using thread

Tags: android

i am try to change relative layout background color like blink first set green and after set white background color in relative layout.but, my problem thread execute second time force close error occurs and try to fix lot of way but doesn't work.
here's my code:

```
       isThreadRunning = true;
       relative=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
       Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                   int i=0;
                   while(isThreadRunning) {
                       if(i==0)
                       {
                       relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                       i=1;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                         relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                         i=0;
                       }
                       try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 

                   }
               }
               };
               new Thread(runnable).start();
```

and i am getting error in logcat like below:

```
07-10 17:48:42.752: W/dalvikvm(2060): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2932)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:642)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:668)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5279)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundDrawable(View.java:7626)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(View.java:7516)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at com.example.screen_blinker.Home_activity$1.run(Home_activity.java:44)
07-10 17:48:42.756: E/AndroidRuntime(2060):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

What' wrong in my code and how to fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code as use [runOnUiThread](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=runonuithread&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFQQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html&ei=YyH8T5rCPJDkrAef2LDBBg&usg=AFQjCNEVbcf_xF52Np66Qp881y0W1JzaTQ) for Updating UI elements from NON UI Thread:

```
public void myThread(){
    Thread th=new Thread(){

     @Override
     public void run(){
      try
      {
       while(isThreadRunning)
       {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             if(i==0)
            {
               relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
               i=1;
            }
            else
              {
               relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
               i=0;
              }

           }
       });
       }
      }catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
   }
}
    };
    th.start();
   }
```

Comment: It's a bad idea to put the whole thing inside `runOnUiThread` because it's pointless having a separate thread in that case.

Comment: then you give me -1 vote.but you can look at my answer which i have placed inside runOnUiThread

Comment: If someone were to implement your answer, they would end up with an activity starting a separate thread which enqueues the entire task of the thread back on the main thread. No need for the separate thread then in the first place.

Comment: you mean relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); in not part of UI thread you can update relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); line from backgrond thread???

Comment: yes i want to run on background thread i am try your code always my app hangs doesn't open shows alert like forceclose or wait!

Comment: @HeroVsZero : see my edit answer just call myThread() after `relative=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);` and make `i` global means outside onCreate of Activity

Comment: @HeroVsZero :and also comment your current `Runnable runnable` thread code

Comment: I'm sorry, I was mislead by the indentation, I thought you included the sleep part in the `runOnUiThread` runnable. I'm revoking my downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change view elements only in main thread. If you in another thread, use this:

```
    Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
```

Comment: i am try your code but not open app always blank i want run thread on background and i am start thread in onCreate() method!

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform GUI related tasks on the GUI thread.

Wrap your `relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` in `runOnUiThread` like so:

```
Current_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            relative.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);               
        }
```

Comment: i am try your code but not open app always blank i want run thread on background and i am start thread in onCreate() method!